# Как получить Int из Drawable?

Tags: java, android, массивы, drawable

Если имеется массив `int[] = new int[]{drawable1, drawable2};` то элементы в нем содержащиеся уже являются сами по себе `int`.

Я достаю `drawable` из кнопки, вот так:

```
Drawable d1 = SG6Button1.getDrawable();
```

Вопрос в том как мне преобразовать его в `int`?
Это необходимо для сравнения с массивом, подобным тому что указан выше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что это невозможно. Но есть альтернативный подход - Записывать, в какой `View` вы установили какой `Drawable`.
Это можно реализовать, например, складывая соответствия в `Map<View, Integer>`, в котором ключом будет `View`, а значением - `id` ресурса.

Еще как вариант, у каждого `View` есть поле `Tag` (`Object getTag()`, `void setTag(Object tag)`), в которое вы можете записывать `id` ресурса при установке его во `View`, и для проверки делать что-то вроде:

```
SG6Button1.setTag(R.drawable.drawable1);
...

Integer id = (Integer ) SG6Button1.getTag();
if(id != null) {
    //это значит, что можно использовать id
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Тоже подумал о таком способе.

Comment: Скажите, а будет ли равен `R.drawable.drawable1` который я задаю в `setTag`  `R.drawable.drawable1` который содержится в массиве `int[] = new int[]{R.drawable.drawable1, R.drawable.drawable2};` ?  Ведь они оба `Int`.

Comment: @ВАНЕЧКА, да, будет. Вы, кстати, лучше сами это проверьте в дебаге, или при помощи логов, например :)