# Конвертация drawable в int

Tags: java, android, конвертация

Создал приложение и картинку:

```
        courseImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("Image",0));
```

создал проверку на эдентичность элементов:

```
if(courseImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("courseImage",0))==courseImage.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_java)){

}
```

и получил ошибку:
**Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'void', 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable'**
Как можно конверттировать в значение int?

Comment: метод setImageResource ничего не возвращает - вот вы и видите ошибку компиляции. Не вполне понятно зачем вам сравнивать картинки в ImageView, однако можно попробовать сравнивать Drawable, полученный из ImageView так: `courseImage.getDrawable().getConstantState() == courseImage.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_java).getConstantState()`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить Int из Drawable?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545302/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-int-%d0%b8%d0%b7-drawable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сути это условие можно упростить до сравнения `id`, сами картинки доставать ради этого не имеет смысла - так как если идентификаторы равны, то и картинки идентичны:

```java
if(getIntent().getIntExtra("courseImage", 0) == R.drawable.ic_java) {

}
```

Comment: Я изменил вопрос, там из-за проверок на картинки ероры выходят, можете помочь?

Comment: Вот так не надо делать, один вопрос - одна проблема. Если у вас появилась другая проблема - задавайте новый вопрос. Тем более что ошибка никак не связана с изначальной темой вопроса.